Why do instances of my custom class have different id's if they hold the same value but with built-in int is the same IDs?
In python, when I create three objects from built-in type int, and give them the same value, they will have the same reference, but when I create three objects from my class and give them the same value, they will have difference references. Why?
example :
A=20
B=20
C=20

print(id(A))
print(id(B))
print(id(C))

#All the objects give me the same reference 

#but my class


A= MyClass()
B= MyClass()
C= MyClass()


print(id(A))
print(id(B))
print(id(C))
#All the objects give me difference reference

I tried very much but I am confused exactly in referencing

The reason this happens is because of optimization. Python stores a few integers (a couple hundred) in cache (from -5 to 256 to be precise). Therefore, whenever you create an instance of the int type within that range, it will always have the same id. Try doing
A=20_000
B=20_000
C=20_000

print(id(A))
print(id(B))
print(id(C))

and see it for yourself.

Yes, if you x = - 6; y = - 6; assert id(x) != id(y) , it'll work just fine.

id(A) == id(B) == id(C) is True when I try it. There's another layer to this that you're missing.

I believe this could be the case if you're not using the CPython implementation of Python. Here's the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong.
